# Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress - Fetch posts based on related post object sub fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

- I have 2 custom post types - event and client-zone.
- Event contains group field "meta" and subfield "date-end"
- Client zone contains post object field and I assign exactly 1 event to each client zone post. Each event has its own client zone post, so 1 to 1. I didn't turn on bidirectional setting.

I need to select all client-zone posts where meta date-end of related event is no older than 1 year.

```php
$data_client_zone = new WP_Query([
    'post_type'         => POST_TYPE_CLIENT_ZONE,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,

    'meta_query'     => [
        // Here I don't know how to target event field and its meta
        [
            'key'       => 'meta_date-end',
            'value'     => date('Ymd', strtotime('-1 year')),
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no way to get this done by a single `WP_Query`. First you'll have to get all events no older than 1 year. Posts returned by `WP_Query` here will be an array of ids.

```php
$data_event = new WP_Query([
    'post_type'         => POST_TYPE_EVENT,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'fields'            => 'ids',
    'meta_query'        => [
        [
            'key'       => 'meta_date-end',
            'value'     => date('Ymd', strtotime('-1 year')),
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Then you need to query client zones comparing `client_zone_event` custom field against previously created array od events ids . For this specific code I assumed that `client_zone_event` custom field is configured to return post ID.

```php
$data_client_zone = new WP_Query([
    'post_type'         => POST_TYPE_CLIENT_ZONE,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_query'        => [
        [
            'key'       => 'client_zone_event',
            'value'     => $data_event->posts,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        ],
    ],
]);
```